# Finding non-recurrent sequences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to figure out the non-recurrent and recurrent sequences. I can give many examples to recurrent sequences but it seems like i cannot find any other examples of non recurrent sequences except prime numbers (2,3,5,7,11...)
Can anyone give me a non recurrent sequence example which can be calculated using an algorithm? (I can calculate prime numbers in C++ for example..)
Thank you

Comment: anything that is prime dependant, for example $\tau(n),\varphi(n), \Omega(n), \omega(n)$ etc..